# How to handle spaces in database name for Sql server CREATE TABLE?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, database, vb.net

I have the following code and I use it in a vb.net project. this works well if there is no space in the database name. for example if the database name is "SampleCompany" it works fine but if the database name changes to "Sample Company"
we recive an error in this section of sql command : "BEGIN CREATE TABLE " & cn.Database.
We must be able to handle database names with/without spaces .

any suggestion to solve this problem ?
Thank you.

```
cn.Database="Sample Company"

sqlCreate = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE      TABLE_NAME = 'Cloud_UserSetting' AND TABLE_CATALOG ='" & cn.Database & "') " & _
            "BEGIN CREATE TABLE " & cn.Database & ".dbo.Cloud_UserSetting(CloudId int NOT NULL, Name varchar(100) NOT NULL," & _
            "Setting varchar(250) NULL " & _
            "CONSTRAINT PK_Cloud_UserSetting PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(CloudId,Name)) END"
command = New SqlCommand(sqlCreate, cn)
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Spaces aren't allowed in identifiers unless it's a delimited identifier. "Sample Company" as ANSI SQL, or perhaps [Sample Company]  MS style.

Comment: To add to what Jarlth said, either double-quotes or square brackets can be used to enclose identifiers in Microsoft SQL Server.  The `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` setting must be on to use the ANSI-standard double-quotes.

Answer (score 9):

use square brackets to contain the column names and table names.

E.g.: instead of `table name` use: `[table name]`

Comment: @User1162527: alternatively if you care for compatibility with the SQL standard you can also use double quotes: `"table name"` (you need to enable QUOTED_IDENTIFIER if I'm not mistaken)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use square brackets in your database name like below :

```
cn.Database="[Sample Company]"

sqlCreate = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE      TABLE_NAME = 'Cloud_UserSetting' AND TABLE_CATALOG ='" & cn.Database & "') " & _
            "BEGIN CREATE TABLE " & cn.Database & ".dbo.Cloud_UserSetting(CloudId int NOT NULL, Name varchar(100) NOT NULL," & _
            "Setting varchar(250) NULL " & _
            "CONSTRAINT PK_Cloud_UserSetting PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(CloudId,Name)) END"
command = New SqlCommand(sqlCreate, cn)
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```